# Where do I leave freeglut.dll without admin rights?

Tags: c++, dll, freeglut

I have installed freeglut to develop with openGL in Visual Studio 2008. But when playing the exe after building, freeglut.dll can't be found. This is quite logical, because I haven't put it into C:\Windows\System32. I can't, because I'm no admin.

What I would like to do now is copy the dll to the ouput folder. I've already put the freeglut.dll into my project folder, but didn't add it to my project. In what way should I set this one up to get freeglut.dll in my output folder?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a post build step that copies that dll from your project folder to the output one.

Under your project properties, Post-Build event, put a command line that copies the file from its source location to `${OutDir}`

Comment: Do I need to include this DLL in my project in VS somehow? Or do I just assume that the dll is there?

Comment: You don't need to add it to your project. As long as the dll is beside your executable, it'll get loaded.

Comment: You don't add it to your project but you still need to set your project to link against it though.